# copy constructor for a linked list classes

Tags: c++

So I want to copy a whole linked list classes, I have trouble figuring it out how to do so,

```
class list{
   public:
  list(const list &t);
private:
  struct Node{
    int x;
    Node *next;
  }*p;
```

I started with something like this:

```
list::list(const list &t){
  Node* q;
  q=new Node;
  while (p!=NULL){
    q->x= p->x;}
}
```

but I'm not sure if I am on the right track or what. I also have trouble how should I test such a copy constructor? For example I have list l1, then i insert couple integers into a list and then how I can copy it?

Comment: I would personally make the copy constructor private and undefined so that copying was impossible. I have literally seen C++ programs that should have executed in seconds take 10 minutes because of undue copying of parameters that should have been passed by reference. `const` reference if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example it never will work if you initialized p or will work forever if `p != NULL`. You must allocate new nodes while traversing through `t list`:

```
  p = NULL;
  Node* copy = l.p;
  Node* insert = p;
  Node* inserted_el = NULL;
  while (copy){
     insert = new Node(); 
     insert->x = copy->x; 
     insert->next = NULL;
     if (inserted_el) {
         inserted_el->next = insert; //copy memory pointer to next element
     } else {
         p = insert; //copy memory pointer to list head
     }
     copy = copy->next;
     inserted_el = insert;
  }
```

This is basic idea. Also don't forget to implement assign operator and destructor.
Usage:

```
list t1;
//insert nodes
list t2(t1);
```

Comment: and how would you call that function to copy? because what i was trying to do is that i have a inserted couple of nodes in a list l1 and then list copy=l1, but it doesn't work

Comment: destructor is now commented, and also when i comment out the print statement, it works...

Answer (score 1):

The biggest trouble in your code is that you do not duplicate each node of the list while you need to do so.

Here is the code of the ctor:

```
list::list(const list &t)
{
  p = NULL;            // Init the head of the list this is vital important.

  // Loop over the elements of the passed list if any.
  Node *pt = t.p;
  Node *last_local_element = NULL;
  while (pt != NULL)
  {
     // Allocate a new node and set the fields there.
     Node *q = new Node;
     q->x= pt->x;
     q->next = NULL;

     // Add new node to the local list.
     if (last_local_element != NULL) {
         last_local_element->next = q;
     } else {
         p = q;
     }

     last_local_element = q;

     // Shift the loop variable along the passed list.
     pt = pt->next;
  }
}
```

There are 2 most often cases when the copy ctor is called:

```
list my_list1;

list my_list2(my_listl);           // Explicit call.
list my_list3 = my_listl;          // Assignment in the definition statement.
```

Answer (score 1):

With your design of class, you need to be careful with memory management. This is the code:

```
list::list(const list& t) {
  Node* n = t.p;
  Node* m = p;
  while (n) {
    if (!m) {
      m = new Node(); // Allocate memory.
      if (!p) p = m;
    }
    m->x = n->x;
    m = m->next;
    n = n->next;
  }

  if (m) { // Original list is longer, delete the rest of the list.
    Node * tmp = m;
    m = m->next;
    delete tmp;
  }
}
```